# Big O proof for logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

Taking a class in discrete math and going through one of the textbook examples, I am asked to prove that

$T(n)$ is $O(\log{}n)$

Where $T(n)= 5\log_{2} (2n) +7$.
I understand that this means that I must prove that $5\log_{2} 2n +7 \leq\lambda \log(n)$ for some $\lambda$, for $n$ in a neighborhood of infinity. How exactly would I proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write inequality as $\lambda \geq 5+\frac{12}{\log_2 n}$ which is satisfied by all $\lambda \geq 17$ and constant $n_0=2$. This gives a tight upper bound and also proves that $T(n)=O(\log_2 n)$.

Comment: IMO, the proof must be given for the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Solve

$$\lambda\ln n\ge5\frac{\ln n+\ln2}{\ln 2}+7$$ or

$$\lambda\ge\frac5{\ln 2}+\frac{12}{\ln n}.$$

As of $n=2$, $\lambda=25>\dfrac{17}{\ln 2}$ is good enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some simple rules to work with `O`.

First rewrite $T(n)$ as $5(1+\log n)+7=5\log n+12$. Then combine these rules:

- $12=O(1)$, and $f=O(1)\implies f=O(\log n)$
- $5\log n=O(\log n)$ by definition
- $O(\log n)+O(\log n)=O(\log n)$

*Detailed computations:*

$12<\log n$ for $n>2^{12}=4096$, hence $T(n)<6\log n$ for $n>4096$.

Comment: the way that I was asked was to to pick some n>a and then using inequality rules build up from there until i get some value for lambda

Comment: OK: I've added a computational version.